# Anchor point disappeared in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In illustrator 'direct selection tool' always automatically shows Bezier handle if I select something (in old times), But suddenly it stopped doing that. It shows nothing if I select the shape , only blue boundary and if I drag the shape then the Bezier handle appears.

I want my old illustrator  back. How can I do that.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think Edges are hidden on your illustrator. Try `Ctrl` + `H` if you are using windows, `Cmd` + `H` for Mac.

[image]